# VBA WORD. Как убрать в документе интервалы между абзацами?

Tags: vba, ms-word, макросы

Хочу в документе убрать все интервалы между абзацами. Пробовал такой код, но интервал остается

```
Sub SetFontNameSize()
With Selection
.WholeStory
.Paragraphs.Space1 ' интервал междустрочный = 1
.Paragraphs.Format.SpaceAfter = 0
.Paragraphs.Format.SpaceBeforeAuto = 0
.Paragraphs.Format.SpaceAfterAuto = 0
End With
End Sub
```

[image: Изображение из Ворд]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    .SpaceBefore = 0
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfter = 0
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
```